# Single keymap to Preview in browser in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, preview, keymaps

Is possible configure a single hit key to Preview in browser in PhpStorm?

The key map to preview in browser works fine, but don't select the default browser and show the choose browser dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `Settings (Preferences on Mac) | Appearance & Behavior | Keymap`
2. Locate `Other | Open in default browser` action (you may use search box -- much faster)
3. Assign any custom shortcut

   [image]